# Who was Scathach and Aoife?

Tags: celtic, irish

Back in September, I was reading a series called, "The Secrets of the Immortal Nicholas Flamel," by Michael Scott. One of the main characters was The Warrior Maiden, Scathach. In this series, she had a twin sister, Aofie, and an unnamed brother.

Who are they in mythology?

Comment: You know the drill:What has your research shown you so far?

Comment: solsdottir's deleted answer is correct. *(If that answer is not resurrected, I'll come back and formally answer, with links.)*  I highly recommend reading the Ulster Cycle.  The [Eickhoff translation](https://www.amazon.com/Red-Branch-Tales-Ulster-Cycle/dp/0312870183) is quite good imo.  There you'll get to read about not only Scatach and Aiofe, but Fergus mac Roth and, [Ket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cet_mac_M%C3%A1gach) and [MacDatho's Boar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conall_Cernach#Mac_Da_Th%C3%B3's_Pig).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1) Who is Scáthach?**

Scáthach is the warrior woman who varyingly lives in the *'east of the world'* who Cú Chulainn is sent to train with:

> Then Domnall said that Cuchulind would not have profession of
>   instruction until he came to Scathach, who was in the east of Alba. So
>   the three of them went across Alba, viz. Cuchulind, and Conchobar, the
>   king of Emain, and Loegaire the Victorious. [Tochmarc Emire, Rawlinson
>   B. 512, Trans. Kuno Meyer]

and ...

> « Is there in the world a woman-knight who is better than the
>   woman-knight with whom I am now? » asks Cuchulainn.  « There is »,
>   answers the big man : « for Scáthach daughter of Buanuinne, king of
>   Scythia, in the east of the world, is better than she. » [Do Fogluim
>   Chonculainn Annso Sios, Egerton 106, Trans. Whitley Stokes]

Her training is seemingly famous and well known

> Then four Irishmen who were in the steading to be trained came to him,
>   and gave him many kisses, and were asking him news of their own
>   country and land ; and he asked them news in the same way.  « Well, O
>   vouths », says Cuchulainn, « what training in feats of valour and
>   warfare have ye got in the year ? »  « We have got », they answer, «
>   the Bridge of the Leaps. »  « How long were ye learning it ? » asks
>   Cuchulainn.  « A training of a quarter and a month and a year and
>   three days and three nights. »  « Well then, O youths », says
>   Cuchulainn, « will ye give me guidance to it ? »  « Alas, O boy »,
>   they say, « what profit were that to thee until Scáthach comes to
>   teach thyself like every one else ? »  « I wish to see it », saith he.
>   [Do Fogluim Chonculainn Annso Sios, Egerton 106, Trans. Whitley
>   Stokes]

...

> Then they bade farewell to Scáthach, and paid the fees for their
>   training by her ; and tidings of them are not told till they reached
>   the country of the men of Catt. [Do Fogluim Chonculainn Annso Sios,
>   Egerton 106, Trans. Whitley Stokes]

**2) Who is Aoife?**

Aoife is another warrior woman who Scáthach seems to have an ongoing feud with:

> At that time also Scathach had a feud against other tribes, over whom
>   was the princess Aife.
>
> ... she was afraid of Aiffe, because she was the hardest woman-warrior
>   in the world.  [Tochmarc Emire, Rawlinson B. 512, Trans. Kuno
>   Meyer]

Cú defeats her in combat and trades her life for three wishes:

> Then they fought upon the path, Cuchulind and Aiffe. Then she broke
>   Cuchulind's weapon so that his sword was no longer than its hilt. Then
>   Cuchulind said : « Woe is me ! » said he, « Aiffe's charioteer and her
>   two chariot-horses have fallen dovvn the glen, and all have perished.
>   » At that Aiffe looked up. At that Cuchulind approached her, seized
>   her under her breast, threw her across (his shoulder) like a burden,
>   and went to his own host.
>
> ... « Life for life ! » she said.  « My three wishes to me ! » said
>   he.  « Thou shalt have them. »  « These are my three wishes : thou to
>   give hostages to Scathach without ever again opposing her, to be with
>   me this night before thy own dun, and to bear me a son. »
>
> It is granted thus and was all done. Then she said she was pregnant.
>   She also said that it was a son she would bear, and that the boy would
>   come to Erin that day seven year. And he left a name for him.
>   [Tochmarc Emire, Rawlinson B. 512, Trans. Kuno Meyer]

Aoife being Scáthach's sister seems to only be found in one translation of a text, I've only found it in Kuno Meyers translation of *Aided Óenfhir Aífe 'The death of Aífe's only son (lit. Violent death [of] One-Man [of] Aífe)'* where we see the two lines:

> .. Scathach Uanaind, daughter of Ardgeimm, in Letha, until he attained
>   mastership of feats with her. And Aife, daughter of Ardgeimm ... [Aided Óenfhir Aífe, Yellow Book of Lecan, Tans. Kuno Meyer]

I haven't found this connection in any other text.

**3) Who is the un-named brother?**

Scáthach has plenty of children (that Cú kills) and family, but I can't find any brother, there could be one referenced in other texts, but none I've looked at.

**Sources:**

1. [Tochmarc Emire, Rawlinson B. 512, Trans. Kuno Meyer](http://sejh.pagesperso-orange.fr/keltia/version-en/wooemer1.html)
2. [Do Fogluim Chonculainn Annso Sios, Egerton 106, Trans. Whitley Stokes](http://sejh.pagesperso-orange.fr/keltia/version-en/cu-training.html)
3. [Aided Óenfhir Aífe, Yellow Book of Lecan, Tans. Kuno Meyer](https://www.jstor.org/stable/30007938?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents)

Comment: Your answer is way better than mine. It can stay deleted.

Answer (score 2):

I recall that Scathach taught martial arts to Cú Chulainn on the Isle of Skye.

Wikipedia confirms this:

> Scáthach (Scottish Gaelic: Sgàthach an Eilean Sgitheanach), or Sgathaich, is a figure in the Ulster Cycle of Irish mythology. She is a legendary Scottish warrior woman and martial arts teacher who trains the legendary Ulster hero Cú Chulainn in the arts of combat. Texts describe her homeland as Scotland (Alpeach); she is especially associated with the Isle of Skye, where her residence Dún Scáith, or "Dun Sgathaich" (Fortress of Shadows), stands.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sc%C3%A1thach)[2] She is called "the Shadow" and "Warrior Maid" and is the rival and sister of Aífe, both daughters of Árd-Greimne of Lethra.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sc%C3%A1thach

Answer (score -5):

All I know is reality, not mythology. And I had never heard that Scota had a twin sister or brother, I wonder if that is part of her legend or made up.

Scáthach was commonly known as Scota, progenitor of the Scots and probably a good bit of the Irish. She was born Ankhesenamun Tasherit, hereditary princess of Egypt. Her successful escape from the clutches of the Egyptian priesthood, and her success at evading the assassins sent to kill her, is the source of legends. She did not have a sister but rather a famous cousin Meritaten Tasherit, also hereditary princess, which was a royal title meaning matrilineally descended from the primordial queen of Egypt. Meritaten also escaped the Priesthood to become Miriam, the founding matron of the Jews. Her ‘brother’ was Thutmosis V aka Moses. So the sister and brother really meant cousins.

Comment: I'm skeptical of basically *every claim* made here. Do you have sources for this narrative?