# Aoife and Cu Chulainn

Tags: irish, interpretation, ulster-cycle

In the Irish legend, did Aoife ultimately win or lose the duel with Cu Chulainn? Is it true that Cu Chualainn fell in love with Aoife?

Answer (score 2):

I basically answer this question from the sources in another question [here](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/3372/who-was-scathach-and-aofie) so I'll modify it for your question.

Aoife is a warrior woman who Cú's teacher Scáthach seems to have an ongoing feud with:

> At that time also Scathach had a feud against other tribes, over whom
>   was the princess Aife.
>
> ... she was afraid of Aiffe, because she was the hardest woman-warrior
>   in the world.  [Tochmarc Emire, Rawlinson B. 512, Trans. Kuno
>   Meyer]

So naturally, he helps out Scáthach when Aoife comes to fight and goes against her in combat, though he won through trickery rather than combat when she gets the upper hand:

> Then they fought upon the path, Cuchulind and Aiffe. Then she broke
>   Cuchulind's weapon so that his sword was no longer than its hilt. Then
>   Cuchulind said : « Woe is me ! » said he, « Aiffe's charioteer and her
>   two chariot-horses have fallen dovvn the glen, and all have perished.
>   » At that Aiffe looked up. At that Cuchulind approached her, seized
>   her under her breast, threw her across (his shoulder) like a burden,
>   and went to his own host. [Do Fogluim Chonculainn Annso Sios, Egerton 106, 
>   Trans. Whitley Stokes]

As for the loving each other bit, no way. Cú trades her life in return for her bearing him a son, medieval sources tend to include *a lot* of rape which gets scrubbed out in modern retellings.

> ... « Life for life ! » she said.  « My three wishes to me ! » said
>   he.  « Thou shalt have them. »  « These are my three wishes : thou to
>   give hostages to Scathach without ever again opposing her, to be with
>   me this night before thy own dun, and to bear me a son. »
>
> It is granted thus and was all done. Then she said she was pregnant.
>   She also said that it was a son she would bear, and that the boy would
>   come to Erin that day seven year. And he left a name for him.
>   [Tochmarc Emire, Rawlinson B. 512, Trans. Kuno Meyer]

**Sources:**

1. [Tochmarc Emire, Rawlinson B. 512, Trans. Kuno Meyer](http://sejh.pagesperso-orange.fr/keltia/version-en/wooemer1.html)
2. [Do Fogluim Chonculainn Annso Sios, Egerton 106, Trans. Whitley Stokes](http://sejh.pagesperso-orange.fr/keltia/version-en/cu-training.html)